# fglrx-updates not working on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, fglrx

I installed `fglrx-updates` and `fglrx-amdcccle-updates` packages. Then also executed the command `amdconfig --initial`.

My system started and all was fine. Then I started amdcccle(AMD Catalyst Control Center) as root using sudo amdcccle and changed the graphics driver to Intel instead of AMD to reduce power consumption. It displayed that I need to reboot my system for the changes to take place.

Now after restarting my system, the task bar(or the top bar) isn't displayed. I am using Ubuntu GNOME 14.10.

fglrx driver problem was there in 14.04 too but I thought maybe due to latest changes in the driver switching, this might be happening. But now, even in 14.10, and Linux image 3.16 also, this problem continues to annoy me.

I am using `tlp` currently for managing the power but this isn't a good habit since it reduces the CPU clock speed which slows down the system.

My system details:

```
Dell Inspiron 7520
Intel HD 4000
AMD 7730M HD
Intel 3rd Gen core i7: 2.2 Ghz.
```

Comment: Try removing your /etc/X11/xorg.conf. I have the same laptop and whenever I ran into this problem, this action solves.

Comment: That file doesn't even exist for me.
Will that appear after installing the driver? I removed it to make my laptop work.

Comment: @Tico
See this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8fpypor9okftjy/Screenshot%20from%202014-12-27%2019%3A24%3A12.png?dl=0

Comment: Yeah, I have the same issue, even after running the `aticonfig --initial` command, there's no xorg.conf. I guess X looks at another conf file? So, now that you're able to boot. Download the Intel Drivers with Synaptic (if you don't have it, `sudo apt-get install synaptic`); Search for intel and download all the xorg packages related. If that doesn't solve your problem, you can download the official Intel Drivers from here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads ;  Mine is working flawlessly, even running HW video decodification. The issue only occurs when you use the Intel GPU?

Comment: Also, use `ì8kmon` for controlling the temp and fan speed, this tutorial helped me a lot: https://davidmarshallblog.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/fixing-linux-mint-on-dell-7520-15r-se-heating-and-graphics/

One thing I notice was that running some packages for power management, the temp was even higher. So consider, if you want, removing `tlp`

Comment: @Tico: Yes this happens only after I choose Intel graphics after restart. If I keep using the AMD graphics, there's no problem. But heating problem pops up.

Comment: @Tico: tlp does help a lot. That's not a problem. In fact without tlp the fan speed and heat both go very high. So, removing tlp won't be a good idea.

Comment: With `ì8kmon` my temps are low and I have no problem with Intel/AMD drivers crashing.

Comment: ok. I'll also try the same then. Thnx..!

Comment: @Tico: Thanks a lot..! The i8kmon tools are the thing I was searching for.
In he man page it is mentioned that it is for Dell Inspiron laptops. So yeah works pretty well.
Thanks again.

Comment: Good to know! It is the best temp manager I've found so far!