# 14.10 Fresh Install and FGLRX install issue

Tags: ati, graphics, 14.10, fglrx

I have now spent a good 8 hours trying to resolve this issue.  I have a fresh Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit install and fglrx amd driver.  I then run:  `sudo apt-get update  sudo apt-get upgrade`  I then reboot for good measure.  Then using the "additional drivers" tab i install the FGLRX driver for my AMD 7970 graphics card. Upon restart it hangs on the dreaded purple screen.  After much research it appears I am having a couple of different issues.  The first issue appears to be gpumanager which  overwrites my Xorg.conf file.  So I went ahead and commented out the config file for gpumanager and then run `amdconfig --initial -f`  The '-f' option is necessary because without it the config file will not generate.  I reboot and now it boots into a black screen with just a cursor.  I have tried several workarounds in an attempt to get unity to show up.  Any help would be so much appreciate, you can expect a quick response time from me and I have a fairly decent knowledge of commands so I should be able to provide you with any output you need.  I promise I am not being lazy, I have worn google out trying to solve this on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install fglrx? Look through http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2249841 and try those, it might help.

Comment: I installed it from the SOFTWARE & UPDATES application, under the ADDITIONAL DRIVERS tab.  I installed the FGLRX driver, didn't work. Did fresh install and tried the FGLRX-UPDATES driver, same result.  I also tried both drivers after a fresh install from the command line. sudo apt-get install fglrx  Yeah thanks for the link, that was the original guide I followed.

Comment: It's a dup of http://askubuntu.com/questions/565821/fglrx-updates-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-10?rq=1, anyway.

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I do not have hybrid graphics, there are no Intel components in my system and I am not even able to access the catalyst control center as the person in the other post did.

Comment: I have since done another fresh install and followed several guides found on this site.  It seems that gpumanager is a new issue but once resolving that there is still an underlying issue.  Does anyone know why the usual 'aticonfig -initial' does not work and why i must use the 'aticonfig --initial -f' command.  This may be a hint as to why it is not working.